# Other solution instead of forced shutdown on my linux laptop when software freezes

Tags: debian, shutdown, minecraft

i usualy play Minecraft on my laptop(4 Go, Intel i5 3320M and Intel HD graphics 4000)  using a external usb ssd (on Sparkylinux for have the maximum of ram) and sometime, when i load a world, 5 seconds before, there are very low fps and then it freeze, but all the computer, and i can't do anything. Sometime i wait and Minecraft close itself, sometime the laptop stay in this state for a long time, so i force shutdown (by pressing 5 seconds the on/off button) for restart the system and replay normaly.

I made this post for know if there is a other way to shutdown without the risk of corrupting the files or others consequences.

Thank you

Comment: Check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/127193/414186) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/211199/414186) answers. Basically if you have `Sysrq` enabled you can type `Alt` + `Sysrq` + `f` (or maybe `Alt` + `Print Screen` + `f`). That will kill the apps that (by what I've noticed) are using more resources.

Comment: Enable the SSH server (often enabled by default) and log on from another device. SSH clients are widely available, including on smartphones. Once logged on, kill the blocked processes, or power it off gracefully.